# how to get the value of selected text box value using php

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, checkbox

I have list of properties and i get the list of users who matched to my selection criteria.

I need to send mail to the selected users.

I am check all option to check every user.

and i have text box for every user to change the rent value.

And i selected some user and click on send i need to send mail with value in the textbox.

I want to get the selected text box value in to form submit code.

[image]

in the above image there is a checkbox for every property and checkbob to check all. and i have text box for the price .

when i click on send by selecting some properties i want to send a mail the posted rent value

Here is the sample code.

```
    while($tenant = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo '
        <tr>

            <td>
                <a href="property.php?id='.$pro['id'].'"><img src="'.(($pro['image_1']) ? $pro['image_1'] : 'images/placeholder.png').'" alt="" width="100"></a>
            </td>

            <td><a href="#">'.$name['name'].$tenant['tenant_id'].' </a><br> '.$pro['name'].'</td>

            <td><b>'.$tenant['lease_exp'].'</b><br><i>'.$pro['ready'].'</i></td>

            <td>'.$pro['type'].'</td>

            <td><div class="price"><strong>$</strong><span>'.$tenant['rent_from'].'-'.$tenant['rent_to'].'</span></div><br><br><input type="text" name="new_rent'.$i.'" value='.$pro['rent'].' class="form-control" style="width:30%;" ></td>

            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="rent[]" id="rent'.$i.'" value="'.$tenant['tenant_id'].'"> Send

            </td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#all').change(function(){
    var ckb_status = $("#all").prop('checked');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", ckb_status );
    });
    });
    </script>

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      if(!empty($_POST['rent'])) {
          print_r($_POST);
        foreach($_POST['rent'] as $check) {

            $tenant_profile = "SELECT * FROM tenant where id=".$check;
            $prof = mysqli_query($link, $tenant_profile);
            $profile = mysqli_fetch_array($prof);



            //echo $tenant_profile;
            //echo "</br>";
            //echo $pro['name'];

            echo $_POST['new_rent'];echo "</br>";

            $to      = $profile['email'];
            $subject = 'Price Change Alert';
            $header = "From: ".ADMIN_EMAIL."\r\n"; 
            $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
            $header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
            $header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 
            $message = '' ;
            $message .= "<div><p>Dear User there is a price drop for the property
            <a href='".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/property.php?id=".$pro['id']."'>".$pro['name']."</a></p>
            <p>Owner offering you ".$_POST['new_rent'].". </p>
            <p>please contact the owner for the complete details. </p>
            <p>Owner email id:#</div>";

            $mail1 = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

            if($mail1) { echo 'mail sent successfully'; }


        }// foreach
      } //empty checkbox check
    else  { echo "Plase Check Any Result"; }
    }//submit
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Where is the text box you say?

Comment: he wrote textbox in place of checkbox. @AedixRhinedale

Comment: @AedixRhinedale checkbox is to select the property and for every property there is a text box to add the rent.
I want that rent value in the form submit

Comment: Where do you increment `$i` in the `while` loop that creates the table rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
Count how many checkbox are getting checked. 

$rent=$_POST['rent']; // Changes Done
$SelectedCheckbox=sizeof($rent); // Changes Done
for($i=0;$i<$SelectedCheckbox;$i++)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<?
while($tenant = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="property.php?id='.$pro['id'].'">
                        <img src="images/placeholder.png" alt="" width="100">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#"><?echo $name['name'].$tenant['tenant_id'];?></a><br><?echo $pro['name'];?></td>
            <td><b><?echo $tenant['lease_exp']?></b><br><i><?echo $pro['ready'];?></i></td>
            <td><?echo $pro['type'];?></td>
            <td>
                <div class="price"><strong>$</strong><span><?echo $tenant['rent_from'].'-'.$tenant['rent_to'];?></span></div><br><br>
                <input type="text" name="new_rent[]" value="<?echo $pro['rent']?>" class="form-control" style="width:30%;" ></td> //Changes Done
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="rent[]" id="rent'.$i.'" value="<?echo $tenant['tenant_id'];?>"> Send
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?}>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#all').change(function(){
    var ckb_status = $("#all").prop('checked');
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", ckb_status );
    });
    });
    </script>

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
      if(!empty($_POST['rent'])) 
      {
        print_r($_POST);
        $rent=$_POST['rent']; // Changes Done
        $SelectedCheckbox=sizeof($rent); // Changes Done
        for($i=0;$i<$SelectedCheckbox;$i++) // Changes Done
        {
            $tenant_profile = "SELECT * FROM tenant where id=".$check;
            $prof = mysqli_query($link, $tenant_profile);
            $profile = mysqli_fetch_array($prof);

            echo $_POST['new_rent'];echo "</br>";

            $NewRent=$new_rent[$i]; //Changes Done

            $to      = $profile['email'];
            $subject = 'Price Change Alert';
            $header = "From: ".ADMIN_EMAIL."\r\n"; 
            $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
            $header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
            $header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 
            $message = '' ;
            $message .= "<div><p>Dear User there is a price drop for the property
            <a href='".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/property.php?id=".$pro['id']."'>".$pro['name']."</a></p>
            <p>Owner offering you ".$NewRent.". </p>
            <p>please contact the owner for the complete details. </p>
            <p>Owner email id:#</div>";

            $mail1 = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

            if($mail1) { echo 'mail sent successfully'; }


        }// for
      } //empty checkbox check
    else  { echo "Plase Check Any Result"; }
    }//submit
```

Comment: Why does he need to get the count of checkboxes? `foreach` does this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`$POST['new_rent']` won't find anything, because the text boxes are named `new_rent$i`.

A better way would be to use array names for the checkboxes and text boxes, and use the same `$i` as the array index for both.

```
$i = 0;
while($tenant = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '
    <tr>

        <td>
            <a href="property.php?id='.$pro['id'].'"><img src="'.(($pro['image_1']) ? $pro['image_1'] : 'images/placeholder.png').'" alt="" width="100"></a>
        </td>

        <td><a href="#">'.$name['name'].$tenant['tenant_id'].' </a><br> '.$pro['name'].'</td>

        <td><b>'.$tenant['lease_exp'].'</b><br><i>'.$pro['ready'].'</i></td>

        <td>'.$pro['type'].'</td>

        <td><div class="price"><strong>$</strong><span>'.$tenant['rent_from'].'-'.$tenant['rent_to'].'</span></div><br><br><input type="text" name="new_rent['.$i.']" value='.$pro['rent'].' class="form-control" style="width:30%;" ></td>

        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="rent['.$i.']" id="rent'.$i.'" value="'.$tenant['tenant_id'].'"> Send

        </td>
    </tr>
    ';
    $i++;
}
```

Then you can loop through the arrays and get the corresponding inputs.

```
foreach ($_POST['rent'] as $i => $check) {
    $new_rent = $_POST['new_rent'][$i];
    $tenant_profile = "SELECT * FROM tenant where id=".$check;
    $prof = mysqli_query($link, $tenant_profile);
    $profile = mysqli_fetch_array($prof);



    //echo $tenant_profile;
    //echo "</br>";
    //echo $pro['name'];

    echo $_POST['new_rent'];echo "</br>";

    $to      = $profile['email'];
    $subject = 'Price Change Alert';
    $header = "From: ".ADMIN_EMAIL."\r\n"; 
    $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
    $header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 
    $message = '' ;
    $message .= "<div><p>Dear User there is a price drop for the property
    <a href='".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/property.php?id=".$pro['id']."'>".$pro['name']."</a></p>
    <p>Owner offering you ".$new_rent.". </p>
    <p>please contact the owner for the complete details. </p>
    <p>Owner email id:#</div>";

    $mail1 = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

    if($mail1) { echo 'mail sent successfully'; }


}// foreach
```

Comment: thanks for the code. But it it is not working. I am getting single value or first selected value and the the textbox value is not submitting to the loop.

Comment: I made a mistake. I put `$i` inside the string, but didn't notice that it was made with single quotes, so variables aren't expanded. I changed it to use concatenation.